# How to give a bitmap a unique filename

Tags: android, bitmap, duplicates

I'm trying to determine if an image already exists in a specific directory. The program I'm making handles the saving of the files so I can name them whatever I want and I need to test if a bitmap exists among these files.

Let's assume there are 100 compressed bitmaps (Into jpg format) in this folder. How could I test whether the new bitmap I'm trying to save already exists?

I could make it so that each of the 100 bitmaps have a unique filename relevant to the image (Along the lines of a hash) and then perform the same algorithm on the current bitmap and do a simple File.exists (with the unique filename).

Other than that idea I'm pretty much stumped, and even then I don't know how to hash a bitmap.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to identify images' content or just file names?

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen Well I'm trying to give an image a unique filename so that when I save the current image, I can check if it's unique filename already exists in the directory (Which will indicate a duplicate file exists)

Comment: I think the easiest way to generate a unique file name is using [current time nano](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) as the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the File class?

```java
File file = new File(path);

if(file.exists())      
    //Do something
else
    // Do something else.
```

EDIT:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

md.update(/* PUT THE IMAGE CONTENTS HERE */);
byte[] digest = md.digest();

String uniqueName = Base64.encodeToString(digest, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: TL;DR: I'm trying to automatically give a bitmap a unique filename. Is there any quick way of doing this (For example, hashing the image)

Comment: You could SHA256 hash the image contents and use that as the file name. See my edit.

Comment: what if he have the same image twice. I can think of many reasons why this eligible.

Comment: Read the first line "I'm trying to determine if an image already exists in a specific directory"

Comment: do something else like what? he needs to save the file with another name. you provided no solution there.

Comment: If he wants to know if the current image exists in the directory then hashing the image for the filename is the quickest solution unless you recommend hashing every image in the directory and comparing it....

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: He wants to generate a unique name for each image, but he also doesn't want the same image uploaded more than once, by checking the hash (unique per entity) you can prevent having the same picture of pikachu a million times. If all you want is a unique file name `File.createTempFile` works great. Hope that clears it up?

Answer (score 2):

Datetime in milliseconds:

```
String time = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```

or:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String mseconds = "" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```